# mount.cifs: silencing the "No dialect specified on mount" message

Tags: mount, cifs, autofs

I am using autofs to mount CIFS shares automatically as described in the [German Ubuntu users wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Autofs/#Ganzes-Samba-Netz).
This works perfectly fine, except that every time a share is mounted, a warning message is logged to `/var/log/syslog` stating:

```
kernel: No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
```

I understand that I can prevent that message by specifying an explicit SMB protocol version. I would however prefer to keep the default behaviour of negotiating the highest SMB protocol version supported by both sides, subject to a minimum version of 2.1, just without that annoying message.

Is there a way to just silence that message while keeping the default behaviour?

Comment: We're talking about different things. What you cite is the documentation for the server side. My question is about the client side.

Comment: ok sorry then I do not know an answer :-)